# How to handle client secret in angular code in a public site

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have a problem trying to figure it out for few days, still didn't get any rigid solution.

I have an angular app which will be publicly available so no login or credential is needed to open the website, and user can have an Id as query param. lets' say [www.mysite.com/123](http://www.mysite.com/123)

to retrieve data for 123, I have a backend, that needs authentication with clientId and clientSecret, to get access_token and then call the api with access_token to get information.

If I put clientId and clientSecret in the code a hacker can steal it and will be using it.

There were some suggestion to enable CORS on backend to make sure only requests from my site will be handled. which I already did, but with knowing the clientId and clientSecret even if CORS is enable a hacker can send requests from postaman by adding origin and referrer as header.

I tried Angular Universal for server side rendering hoping the api call will be run on serve side and will be hidden from user, but api call still happing in front end.

Really stuck in this problem any kind of help is appreciated.

Since the application is small and it's only hosting a web component developed by stencilJs, if other languages such as react or vue can support my scenario I can switch

Answer (score 1):

You can go extensive ways of obfuscating statically inserted token in the frontend client build, yet it is still going to be there and the only thing it will add — extra steps for an attacker to reverse it, at least to my knowledge.

So to explore the solution to your problem, i guess you want to define it in the more narrow way, i.e what are you trying to protect:

- resource requiring privilege (admin panel)

  - then your answer will be dynamic auth.
- protect your api from external usage/ddos

  - CORS, ratelimiting, dynamic token issuing(take notice that strategy still will be available inside frontend client code)

also i think owasp guidelines will be a good read on the topic:
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html

I think i should clarify that in my opinion the solution that you are going to implement in the end in the case of the "protection of the api" is going  to be building fences to jump over, rather than sealing api completely from the 3rd party usage.